# CodeEffects exception with .net core 3.1 and running in docker container

Tags: codeeffects

After the upgrade from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 (without changing codeffects related code or library versions) we have problems when loading the xml into the rule editor (in the backend), but only when running the application in a docker container (which is based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1.11 image). When running exactly the same code from Visual Studio everything is fine. Like it is also if we revert to the .net core 2.2 version of the app.

The problem is on loading the existing rule xml into the rule editor:

```
editor.LoadRuleXml(ruleXml);
```

or this way

```
editor.Rule = CodeEffects.Rule.Models.RuleModel.Create(ruleXml, type);
```

The exception is:

> CodeEffects.Rule.Common.InvalidRuleException: Invalid rule XML. Input string was not in a correct format. (#125) at CodeEffects.Rule.Formats.Ce.FillRule(List`1 list, XmlNode ruleXml, XmlDocument sourceXml, GetRuleDelegate ruleDelegate, Type sourceObject) at CodeEffects.Rule.Formats.Ce.LoadXml(XmlDocument rule, XmlDocument source, GetRuleDelegate ruleDelegate, Type sourceObject) at CodeEffects.Rule.Core.RuleLoader.LoadXml(XmlDocument rule, XmlDocument source, RuleFormatType format, GetRuleDelegate getRuleDelegate, Type sourceObject) at CodeEffects.Rule.Core.RuleLoader.LoadXml(String xmlRule, XmlDocument sourceXml, GetRuleDelegate ruleDelegate, Type sourceObject) at CodeEffects.Rule.Web.RuleEditor.LoadRuleXml(String ruleXml, GetRuleDelegate ruleDelegate) at CodeEffects.Rule.Web.RuleEditor.LoadRuleXml(String ruleXml)

Logging the xml that we pass to the load method shows that the xml is as it should be, so like it was stored in the db, and this same xml otherwise works fine, just not when the app is running in a docker based on .net core 3.1.

Unfortunatelly there is no inner exception that would point us closer to the source of the problem. And since it can be only reproduced when running in docker container, we are running out of ideas.

Our version of CodeEffects.Rule.Editor.Web.Core library is quite old, 5.0.7.6, but the same problem persists even if we upgrade to the latest 5.0.38.4.

Any idea what could be the problem?